# Matching triplets with Regular Expression in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to match RNA Codons with Ruby, whereas the match must stop whenever a stop-codon appears. This almost does the trick:

```
"GUUAAUGAGUAAGUAAGUAG" =~/AUG(.*?)(UAA|UAG|UGA)/
puts($&)
-->AUGAGUAA
```

However, it doesn't match in triplets which leads to an untimely stop. It has to be:
`AUG AGU AAG UAA`. Then, there are no more stop-codon-triplets left. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use three dots in the pattern: `/AUG((...)*?)(UAA|UAG|UGA)/`

This way it will only match sequences of length 0, 3, 6, 9, etc.